# boost::stacktrace::safe_dump_to output size

Tags: c++, boost, stack-trace

I'm trying to save a stacktrace to raw memory using the `boost::stacktrace::safe_dump_to(void*, std::size_t)` function, however the function returns the number of stack frames (plus the termination frame) written - **not** the number of bytes written.

This means that when I come to read this data, I have no idea what to put in the size field of `boost::stacktrace::stacktrace::from_dump(const void *, std::size_t, const allocator_type &)`.  At first I assumed that I could use `sizeof(boost::stacktrace::frame) * frames`, but the `frame` type contains heap allocated memory (`std::string`s) so that won't work.

This [SSCE demonstrates](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c191f33060b0a887) the problem:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/stacktrace.hpp>

int main()
{
    auto buf = std::array<char, 8192>{};
    const auto size = boost::stacktrace::safe_dump_to(buf.data(), buf.size());
    const auto st = boost::stacktrace::stacktrace::from_dump(buf.data(), size);

    std::cout << "ST from dump (" << size << " bytes): " << st << std::endl
              << "ST: " << boost::stacktrace::stacktrace{} << std::endl;


    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

It outputs:

```
ST from dump (4 bytes): 
ST:  0# 0x00000000004016A7 in ./a.out
 1# __libc_start_main in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
 2# 0x0000000000401759 in ./a.out
```

The second 'ST' line is just to show what is expected.  The first line fails because I'm trying to treat the frame count as a byte size, which it obviously isn't.

So how is the API supposed to be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the same size on the reading back:

```
const auto st = boost::stacktrace::stacktrace::from_dump(buf.data(), buf.size());
```

After all you used that limit when writing the dump, so the size is known to be smaller than that.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0bd612e75e624fc8)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/stacktrace.hpp>

int main()
{
    auto buf = std::array<char, 8192>{};
    const auto size = boost::stacktrace::safe_dump_to(buf.data(), buf.size());
    const auto st = boost::stacktrace::stacktrace::from_dump(buf.data(), buf.size());

    std::cout << "ST from dump (" << size << " frames): " << st << std::endl
              << "ST: " << boost::stacktrace::stacktrace{} << std::endl;
}
```

Prints

```
ST from dump (4 frames):  0# 0x00000000004016B9 in ./a.out
 1# __libc_start_main in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
 2# 0x0000000000401869 in ./a.out

ST:  0# 0x00000000004017AF in ./a.out
 1# __libc_start_main in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
 2# 0x0000000000401869 in ./a.out
```

### UPDATE

As mentioned in the comment there is a little tidbit about `safe_dump_to` in the docs [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/stacktrace/reference.html#header.boost.stacktrace.safe_dump_to_hpp)

> *Dumps are binary serialized arrays of `void*`, so you could read them by using `od -tx8 -An stacktrace_dump_failename` Linux command or using `boost::stacktrace::stacktrace::from_dump` functions*

Comment: This _feels_ wrong, but I can't immediately think of any technical issues with it.

Comment: It's exactly how this is supposed to be used. Look at the save/dump functions that take streams. They don't afford a size parameter. The size only comes in for statically allocated buffers (because signal/async safe code needs to be allocation free)

Comment: I suppose you could do this: [treat the buffer as a stream](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b59a48e95d2f6f20) which tells you the effective size was 32 bytes. That corresponds to the documentation saying that [_"Dumps are binary serialized arrays of void*, so you could read them by using 'od -tx8 -An stacktrace_dump_failename' Linux command or using boost::stacktrace::stacktrace::from_dump functions"_](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/stacktrace/reference.html#header.boost.stacktrace.safe_dump_to_hpp)

Comment: Please can you add that last point to your answer?  As it's the (naively) exact answer to my question e.g. `from_dump(buf.data(), size*sizeof(void*))`.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer does not seem to answer much the question, IMHO, so I try this one.

As you mentionned, the size we get from safe_dump_to() is a number of frame, not a buffer size.

documentation states:

> Returns:
>
> Stored call sequence depth including terminating zero
> frame. To get the  actually consumed bytes multiply this value by the
> sizeof(boost::stacktrace::frame::native_frame_ptr_t)

so the call should be:

```
const auto st = boost::stacktrace::stacktrace::from_dump(buf.data(),
                     size * sizeof(boost::stacktrace::frame::native_frame_ptr_t));
```